# Xpath Finding when Only name is Present in Selenium

Tags: xml, xpath

How to write `xpath` When only `name` is present. `//input[@name='usr_name']` is not working. I am scripting using `xml` and not `Java`.Below is the line I am looking to find `Xpath` for

```
<input name="usr_name" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: <input name="usr_name" type="text" value=""> This is the line I am trying to find XPATH for

Comment: `//input[@name='usr_name']` is correct `XPath` for your case. Why you think that it `is not working`?